# fadeIn(); fades in then out then back in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZcbUW/

When you hover from the top of the blue div and dont move your mouse, the text fades in, out, then in. I have no idea why.

```
<html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#menu, #arrow").mouseenter(function () {
    $('#arrow').stop(true, false).fadeOut("fast");
    $("body").children(':not(#menu)').children(':not(#arrow)').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(2px)");
    $("#menu").stop().animate({
        width: "300px"
    }, 300, function () {
        $('.text').fadeIn(200);
    });
})
$("#menu").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#menu").stop().animate({
        width: "5px"
    }, 300, function () {
        $('#arrow').stop(true, false).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $("body").children(':not(#menu)').css("-webkit-filter", "none");
    $('.text').fadeOut(100);
});
```

Your selector is weird. So hover is firing on both the menu and the arrow. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcbUW/2/

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
$('.text').fadeOut(100);
```

Works for me with your example.

Comment: Then the text never goes away when you move your mouse off the containing div.

Comment: unfortunately, I need to keep the fadeOut